# incorrect workspace key while installing Log Analytics Agent in Linux machine

Tags: azure, terraform

I got this issue when deploying Log Analytics Agent in Linux machine on Azure cloud.

```
Enable failed with exit code 53 Installation failed due to incorrect workspace key. Please check if the workspace key is correct. For details, check logs in /var/log/azure/Microsoft.EnterpriseCloud.Monitoring.OmsAgentForLinux/extension.log
```

I used terraform script.

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "log_analytic_agent" {
  name                       = "Log-Analytic-Agent-Extension"
  virtual_machine_id         =  module.machine.vm_id

  publisher                     = "Microsoft.EnterpriseCloud.Monitoring"
  type                          = "OmsAgentForLinux"
  type_handler_version          = "1.6"
  auto_upgrade_minor_version    = true


  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
      "workspaceId" : "1323232323232323"
    }
  SETTINGS

  protected_settings = <<PROTECTED_SETTINGS
    {
      "workspaceKey" : "dsdsdsfd434fdvdghtcDW#efggrgrffefef"
    }
  PROTECTED_SETTINGS


}
```

Comment: According to doc: "Certain VM Extensions require that the keys in the protected_settings block are case sensitive. If you're seeing unhelpful errors, please ensure the keys are consistent with how Azure is expecting them"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out, the reason why it got error above.

For installing log analytics agent in linux machine ,we should enble access Outbound from machine to these :

```
*.ods.opinsights.azure.com  Port 443    Outbound    
*.oms.opinsights.azure.com  Port 443    Outbound
*.blob.core.windows.net     Port 443    Outbound
*.azure-automation.net      Port 443    Outbound
```